# Blazor Refreshing Component without ChildContent

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a Container component that simply loops through a list of integers and renders them as li tags.

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var item in Items)
    {
        <li>@item</li>
    }
</ul>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public List<int> Items { get; set; } = new List<int>();

}
```

This component does not trigger a view update unless an unrendered ChildContent is added to it.

In the following example everything works just fine. However, once the `<i />` tag is removed the code stops working. I have no idea what would causes such behavior, however i prefer not to render a useless tag if it can be avoided.

```
@page "/"

<Container @ref="container">
    <i />
</Container>

<button @onclick="Add">Add</button>

@code{

    private Container container;

    void Add()
    {
        container.Items.Add(container.Items.Count);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "stops working"

Comment: I've noticed this behaviour too and can find no explanation @PeterMorris. The example above is perhaps a tad convoluted, basically if you create a component with a ChildContent render fragment and change the state in code, it updates. If you remove the ChildContent and change the state it won't update and you have to call StateHasChanged internally within the component to force a refresh. Definitely some magic going on.

Comment: Can you provide a repro on GitHub so I can fully understand what you mean?