# Blazor weirdness with ChildContent RenderFragment

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

This question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62670114/blazor-refreshing-component-without-childcontent) but resubmitting with a clearer example (hopefully).

I've noticed this strange behaviour when trying to pin down when and how Blazor re-renders and updates state.

Take the following simple component `Test1Component`:

```
@if (_show) {
    <h3>Test1Component</h3>
}

@code {
    private bool _show = true;

    public void Show() {
        _show = true;
    }

    public void Hide() {
        _show = false;
    }
}
```

When used within another component, calling `Show` or `Hide` doesn't do anything:

```
<Test1Component @ref="_test1Component"></Test1Component>

<button type="button" @onclick="(() => { if (_test1Component != null) _test1Component.Hide(); })">Hide Test</button>
<button type="button" @onclick="(() => { if (_test1Component != null) _test1Component.Show(); })">Show Test</button>

@code{
    Test1Component _test1Component;
}
```

In order to get it working you must add `StateHasChanged()` to both the `Show` and `Hide` methods. If however we change the implementation to include a `RenderFragment`, the `Show` and `Hide` methods mysteriously start working.

```
@if (_show) {
    <h3>@ChildContent</h3>
}

@code {
    private bool _show = true;
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    public void Show() {
        _show = true;
    } 

    public void Hide() {
        _show = false;
    }
}
```

The `Show` and `Hide` methods now work, even though all that has changed is the addition of a `RenderFragment`.

```
<Test1Component @ref="_test1Component">Test1Component</Test1Component>

<button type="button" @onclick="(() => { if (_test1Component != null) _test1Component.Hide(); })">Hide Test</button>
<button type="button" @onclick="(() => { if (_test1Component != null) _test1Component.Show(); })">Show Test</button>

@code{
    Test1Component _test1Component;
}
```

My suspicion is that Blazor is registering this component differently somehow behind the scenes because of the `RenderFragment`, tracking its state internally and auto triggering `StateHasChanged` on updates.

It begs the question then, in such a scenario do you as practice use the `StateHadChanged` method to update state or rely on the auto-magically maintained state when a RenderFragment is included?

Does anyone know 1. why is happens? and 2. what is actually happening behind the scenes to make it work? I only noticed this by being very methodical trying to figure out the best way to trigger updates from the ground up but starting off with Blazor it has lead to some confusion as some components would just work and others wouldn't without the `StateHasChanged` being called, the behaviour seemingly random at times with no rhyme or reason. Obviously now it's starting to make sense as to why it's happening.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a component with no `Parameters` the renderer will correctly assume nothing has changed and not bother re-rendering it during the render caused by clicking the `button`

Adding the RenderFragment Parameter forces Blazor's hand - it has to render because it doesn't have any way of detecting whether the Parameter has changed.

The practice of calling public methods of a child component is dubious - if you just included a Parameter such as `bool Hide` and set that from the parent it would all work just fine.